# How to get the values from nodes in tree-sitter?

Tags: c, rust, treesitter

If I have a simple grammar in tree-sitter:

```
rules: {
    expr: $ => choice(
        /[0-9]+/,
        prec.right(seq($.expr, /[+-]/, $.expr)),
    )
}
```

And an input:

```
3+4
```

I get the followng CST:

```
(start [0, 0] - [0, 3]
  (expr [0, 0] - [0, 3]
    (expr [0, 0] - [0, 1])
    (expr [0, 2] - [0, 3])))
```

So my question is, how do I get the values, i.e. what was parsed, from these nodes/leafes. I somehow have to evaluate the tree. I'm certainly sure there is way, because I can also do syntax-highlighting with tree-sitter, for what I need the values (I guess). But I read the documentation and couldn't find any note, how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tree-sitter's syntax tree doesn't store copies of the input text. So to get the text of a particular token, you would have to use the ranges that Tree-sitter gives you to compute *slices* of your original source code.

In the [python binding](https://github.com/tree-sitter/py-tree-sitter), this looks like this:

```py
source_code_bytes = b'3 + 4'
tree = parser.parse(source_code_bytes)
node1 = tree.root_node.children[0].children[0]

node1_text = source_code_bytes[node1.start_byte:node1.end_byte].decode('utf8')
assert node1_text == '3'
```

In some language bindings, like [the wasm binding](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/tree/master/lib/binding_web), there is a `.text` helper for making this easier.

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/tree-sitter/py-tree-sitter/issues/16) for adding this kind of helper function to the python binding.